# Node.js Package.json file error while running Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, npm, package.json, nvm

I am new to using Node.js

I have a project folder structure `C:\A\B\C\`

I have `C:\A\B\C\html_pages\index.html` in which I have React.js code having CDN

and `C:\A\B\C\server.js` which has Express.js code which I want to run.

1. I installed nvm then installed Node.js using command
   `nvm install 4.5`
2. In windows PowerShell, I went to project directory
   `C:\A\B\C` and used `npm init`  (node_modules were not created in this step)
3. Did `npm install express --save` to use the express module (now node_modules folder was created but package.json was inside express folder)
4. Used `npm start` to start the web server but it gave following error.

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\A\B\C\package.json'`
I checked the posts on Stackoverflow for this error but was not able to solve it.
Should the package.json be generated directly under `'C:\A\B\C\` ?
I have installed Node.js in `C:\Program Files\nodejs` while project is not under Program Files, is this related to this?

P.S. : Used npm init --yes so that it installs node_modules inside my project folder and got the request processed but port 3000 gives error that it did not get GET request

Comment: Are you running npm init and npm start both in the C folder?

Comment: Yes in my project folder named C

Comment: package.json is not your problem anymore, you are using or setting the wrong port, or you don't have the GET endpoint you are trying to request. Nothing to do anymore with a package.json error.

Answer (score 1):

The `package.json` file should be on the root of your directory.
Open command line from your root directory and type,

```sh
npm init
```

This will generate a package.json file on that directory.

Comment: I tried the same but it is not created in the root directory. In my directory as I mentioned, I have following structure : ```C:\A\B\C\node_module\express\package.json```

Comment: This is express' package.json (every module has their own), the root folder of your code needs it's own package.json. Your root directory C has the node_modules (your dependencies described in your package.json) does C not have a package.json? It should after running npm init in it.

Comment: when I used npm init --yes it created in C project folder otherwise it was not creating